# Convert raw data to a vector of complex numbers in Thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have a pointer to raw data of complex numbers in interleaved format, i.e. real and imaginary parts stored alternately - R I R I R I ...

How do I convert this to a host (or device) vector of thrust::complex without incurring extra copy?
The following does not work -

```
double dos[8] = {9.3252,2.3742,7.2362,5.3562,2.3323,2.2322,7.2362,3.2352};
thrust::host_vector<thrust::complex<double > > comp(dos, dos+8);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast. Something like this:

```
double dos[8] = {9.3252,2.3742,7.2362,5.3562,2.3323,2.2322,7.2362,3.2352};
typedef thrust::complex<double> cdub;
cdub* cdos = reinterpret_cast<cdub*>(&dos[0]);
thrust::host_vector<cdub> comp(cdos, cdos+4);
```

should work.